# try and except statement not being called

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping ebay for an item's information. The item is not very consistent with some of the info I need so I am using a try/except statement for the code to continue when an index error is arised but for some reason the try/except statement is not being called when the condition is met. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? I have debugged the code but can't find the issue. Thanks

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'}
my_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1311&_nkw=sm-r800&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0' \
         '&_osacat=0&_odkw=samsung+watch '


def get_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, features='html.parser')
    return soup


def parse_data(soup):
    product_list = []
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results:
        try:
            products = {'Title': item.find_all('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})[0].h3.text,
                        'Price': float(item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).text[1:]),
                        'Product Rating': float(item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__reviews'}).a.div.find('span', {
                            'class': 'clipped'}).text.strip(' ')[0]),
                        'Watchers': float(item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__details clearfix'}).find('span', {
                            'class': 's-item__hotness s-item__itemHotness'}).text.split(' ')[0])
                        }
            product_list.append(products)
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return product_list


def output(product_list):
    df = pd.DataFrame(product_list)
    df.to_csv('Samsung Watch Data.csv', index=False)
    print('Saved to CSV')
    return


my_soup = get_data(my_url)
data = parse_data(my_soup)
output(data)
```

Comment: please try `except Exception as e:` to see what exceptions you can get first.

Comment: You're returning on the first iteration of the for loop

Comment: @C.Nivs if I put the try/except statement outside the loop, the continue statement can't be executed. not sure why.

Comment: The placement of your `try/except` is not the issue, it's the `return` statement that's causing the loop to stop

Comment: `return product_list` is inside the for loop, therefore the for loop only iterates once...

Comment: Are you sure your soup has any results in it? What do you mean "the try except isn't being called?" You say you've "debugged your code" but you've now made an edit to get rid of one of your mistakes. Your exception is suppressed silently, are you certain that nothing is happening?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `return` statement, which is causing your loop to end early, because `return` finishes the function execution. To make this easier to see:

```py
def f():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        return 

f()
0
# Nothing else happens here
```

To get all of the numbers, I need the `return` to be at the end of the loop:

```py
def f():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
    return 
0
1
2
# Now I get all of the numbers
```

So move your `return` to the end of your loop, and unindent it:

```py
def parse_data(soup):
    product_list = []
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results:
        try:
            products = {'Title': item.find_all('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})[0].h3.text,
                        'Price': float(item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).text[1:]),
                        'Product Rating': float(item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__reviews'}).a.div.find('span', {
                            'class': 'clipped'}).text.strip(' ')[0]),
                        'Watchers': float(item.find('div', {'class': 's-item__details clearfix'}).find('span', {
                            'class': 's-item__hotness s-item__itemHotness'}).text.split(' ')[0])
                        }
            product_list.append(products)
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return product_list # <---- Here
```

## To ignore any exceptions

Instead of `except IndexError` use `except Exception`. This will catch any kind of exception your code might throw, though I'd *definitely* `print` what kind of error occurred. Catching specific errors is usually better practice:

```py
try:
    # some code
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Caught an exception: {e}")
    continue
```

Comment: I made the corresponding change and it is still crashing. Source code has been updated.

Comment: @SantiagoRestrepoSerna Crashing?  Are you getting an error traceback?

Comment: Since the HTML is not very consistent, I would get an AttributeError or an IndexError depending of the location of the the website that is being parsed at the moment. Ideally I would like the code to ignore all type of errors and continue no mater what

Comment: Then use `except Exception`. If you're to do that, I'd strongly recommend printing *something* letting you know what error happened. Otherwise you could mask bugs

Comment: @SantiagoRestrepoSerna Then use `except:` which catches everything.